# Apple TV4 VLC sees SMB but folder empty

Tags: sharing

I screwed something up. i just got vlc for apple tv 4 and enabled file sharing from my mac mini 2014 running high sierra 10.13.4. it ran great but it allowed anonymous login, so i thought i'd restrict it because I live in high rise and use wifi. Anyway, I deleted some users ('staff', "Everyone") and added a new admin. Now nothing works. vlc recognizes my computer in smb but when i try to access it the folder reads empty. Can't see anything on iphone app, either. is there someway to reset the thing? i tried diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u` in terminal, nothing doing.

Any advice would be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue - VLC would only show empty folders once connected - this was happening from the first time I opened VLC on my Apple TV.
My shares are also on a Mac Mini (2012 model) running 10.13.4
I got it to work by turning off file sharing, then disabling AFP sharing and only using SMB.
Once I turned file sharing back on, VLC could see all my shared folders.
To change sharing options, go into System Preferences, Sharing.

Oh, and I use a password-protected account called 'media' for accessing the shares from networked devices. I don't use anonymous logins.
Hope this helps, or you got the issue sorted already.

I'm also trying out the app 'infuse' and it looks nice, but with some videos it wants me to buy a subscription to use the app to continue, so not sure yet if it's something I'll stick with.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to restore the ATV4 to factory settings. To do this:

1. On your Apple TV go to Settings > System > Reset
2. You'll see two options:

   - **Reset:** This reset your Apple TV to its factory settings and won't update the software. This can be done without an internet connection.
   - **Reset and Update:** As above, this resets your Apple TV to its factory settings, but also installs any available software updates. Obviously you will need an internet connection for this to complete.
3. Once your Apple TV is reset, reconfigure it by adding your Apple ID, etc.
4. Once you've logged back in, re-download the apps you want.

Comment: I’m sorry, Monomeeth, I think my question was incorrectly asked. The problem is the sharing from my Mac mini. It shows up as smb but I can’t access the files.

Comment: Okay, so, when you say in your question *Is there some way to reset the thing?*, what are you wanting to reset?

Comment: Yeah, I’m a little clumsy at this. I’m very sore. I meant reset the file sharing on my Mac mini. Like it was before. I deleted a bunch of things from the sharing option, like public folder. I’m sorry I’m not very clear. I think I might have to reinstall the OS?

Answer (score 0):

If you see only empty folders on your NAS, you should also check if you set correct rights on the account you're using for login on VLC - this is being set on NAS users' account privileges, not on VLC nor Apple TV (ex. for the Synology NAS, you'd need to login via your computer's internet browser, go to the Control Panel -> User -> select user you're using for VLC login and click on Edit and check the privileges - or create a new user with correct privileges).